# AD Module for powershell - can't write back to Active Directory Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

Tags: powershell, active-directory-import

I have a powershell script that imports active directory module , import a .csv file and update a few attributes in AD from SAP. I run windows powershell ISE as administrator.[image]

When I run it under svcSPProfile I get this error [image]

When I run the script under farm account I get this error
[image]

Any ideas what am i missing

Comment: You run the powershell with administrator is not same you be a AD admisnitartor. You have permission in AD to do this?